# Data import is not being joined on custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics

I have a following setup: potential customers do a preorder and can be upgraded to real customers after a period of time. When a preorder is submitted I store the preorder id in custom dimension and set another custom dimension 'realCustomer' to 0. This happens via event, DataLayer is pushed to GTM successfully.

I can see custom data in Analytics. After some time I upload CSV in Data Import. The file contains the preorderId dimension and updated realCustomer dimension (0 becomes 1). The uploads are processed successfully but no matter how long I wait the zeroes are not updated to 1's. The 'overwrite hit data' set to Yes.

I have tried setting my dimensions to Hit, Session and User type and creating new data sets accordingly. Nothing helps and dimensions are not being overwritten or joined.

Anyone has ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between [Query time data import and processing time data import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6071511?hl=en&ref_topic=6064627)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might misunderstand you, but it seems you expect data is changed retroactively. This is not the case - unless you have a premium account (which as of recently can apply uploaded data to historical data) your imports will only affect incoming hits, not data that was already present.

For details see [Query Time Data Import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6071511?hl=en&ref_topic=6064627)

Comment: This is exactly what I expected, Eike. Thank you for your response!
The possibility to set 'Overwrite hit data' to Yes or No confused me, so I thought I could overwrite historical hit data.

Comment: Here is a good summary of what [Overwrite means](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014980?hl=en&ref_topic=6064627#overwrite_behavior) in various scenarios.